# How do I convert a certificate to a private key?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm trying to setup certificates for a web server (Splunk, in particular), and don't think I have them in the right format. I need to provide the path to a private key file, and a CA certificate. Right now, I have both of those in PEM format (the contents of both files start with "----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"). But that doesn't seem to be working, and my best guess is that the private key file needs to be in a different format. Basically, I'd like to have it in a format such that the command

```
openssl rsa -in MYFILE -check
```

succeeds (right now, that fails with "unable to load Private Key"). I can, however, currently verify it with

```
openssl x509 -in MYFILE -text -noout
```

So how can I convert the file so that the first command succeeds on it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A certificate has only the public key, not the private one.

When they're in PEM format, sometimes both the private key and the certificate are in the same file. Look for a `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` or `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` header. If you find one, just separate the two blobs using a regular text editor.

But if you have *only* the certificate, then you absolutely *cannot* get a private key out of it. A certificate has only the public key, and the entire security of asymmetric cryptography depends on the impossibility of finding the private key given the public one.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have both the private key and cert in .pem format (X509) and need to convert that private key to the rsa private key format (RSA)

A method to do that has been provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733536/how-do-i-convert-a-private-key-to-an-rsa-private-key

Comment: The private key with a `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` header is technically in PKCS#8 format – X.509 is strictly about certificates.